# Vaadin 23 artifact generation and Maven multimodule project

Tags: maven, vaadin, vaadin23

I have a Maven multimodule project with the following structure:

```
parent
- domain
- vaadin-ui
```

When I run the vaadin-ui project with a Maven command `mvn spring-boot:run`, Vaadin generates different artifacts on the `domain` and `vaadin-ui` folders level, for example:

```
package.json package-lock.json tsconfig.json types.d.ts webpack.config.js webpack.generated.js
```

Is it possible to let Vaadin know to generate such staff inside the `vaadin-ui` module folder?

Comment: Here if the official example of a multi module project. https://github.com/vaadin/multi-module-example - normally it should be enough to add the Vaadin Maven plugin inside your ui module

Comment: Thank you, that's works except this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73092965/vaadin-23-application-run-from-application-class-vs-maven