# Vaadin 23 application run from Application class vs Maven

Tags: maven, vaadin, vaadin23

When I run my Vaadin 23 application via `Application` Java class from IDEA everything works fine. But whe I run it via Maven with `mvn spring-boot:run` command it fails with the following exception:

```
There was an exception while trying to navigate to '' with the root cause 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanValidationBinder cannot be used because a JSR-303 Bean Validation implementation not found on the classpath or could not be initialized. Use Binder instead'
```

I have

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

declared in Maven dependencies. What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

**UPDATED**

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <artifactId>example</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>ui</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.source.version>17</java.source.version>
        <java.target.version>17</java.target.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <file.encoding>UTF-8</file.encoding>

        <vaadin.version>23.1.3</vaadin.version>

        <com.example.domain.version>0.0.1</com.example.domain.version>
        <spring-data-neo4j.version>5.3.9.RELEASE</spring-data-neo4j.version>

    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->

        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <value.converter.key>******</value.converter.key>

                <upload.dir>uploads</upload.dir>

                <logging.file>ui.log</logging.file>
            </properties>

            <build>
                <plugins>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                        <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <properties>
                <value.converter.key>*******</value.converter.key>

                <upload.dir>uploads</upload.dir>

                <logging.file>ui.log</logging.file>
            </properties>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <value.converter.key>******</value.converter.key>

                <upload.dir>/srv/domain/uploads</upload.dir>

                <logging.file>/var/log/tomcat/ui.log</logging.file>
            </properties>

            <build>
                <plugins>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                            <pnpmEnable>false</pnpmEnable>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- example -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
            <version>${com.example.domain.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-neo4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility mode -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Excluding so that webjars are not included. -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.artur</groupId>
            <artifactId>a-vaadin-helper</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.artur.exampledata</groupId>
            <artifactId>exampledata</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.zip</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.zip</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.zip</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.zip</include>
                </includes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                    <delimiters>
                        <delimiter>${*}</delimiter>
                    </delimiters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Clean build and startup time for Vaadin apps sometimes may exceed the default Spring Boot's 30sec timeout.  -->
                <configuration>
                    <wait>500</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--
                      Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in
                      package.json and main.js files.
                      It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.
                  -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: That's very strange. How does your pom.xml look like?

Comment: I updated my question and added the pom.xml

Comment: I can't see a problem. Can you provide a producible example?

Comment: I can see that your project has been Vaadin 14 and you still have webjar exclusions there. If you have upgraded to Vaadin 23, you can drop them. But this is not related to your actual problem.

Comment: As a basis I selected the following example https://github.com/vaadin/flow-crm-tutorial As a standalone project, it works fine with `mvn spring-boot:run` command. But when I connect my Maven module, which contains all of my business logic, it fails with the issue above. Unfortunately, I'm unable to share the source of the Maven module. But I may try to export all Maven dependencies from them

Comment: This is the project Maven dependency tree https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CZ0RwUnNr8jpo1QrjTlM6XN407AzIFSS/view?usp=sharing